# Why is Shiny a dependency of devtools?

Tags: r, devtools

When I install devtools, I get shiny as a dependency.

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘/Users/xxx/tmp/xxx/packrat/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/3.5.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘zeallot’, ‘colorspace’, ‘utf8’, ‘vctrs’,
 ‘plyr’, ‘labeling’, ‘munsell’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘fansi’, ‘pillar’,
 ‘pkgconfig’, ‘httpuv’, ‘xtable’, ‘sourcetools’, ‘fastmap’, ‘gtable’,
 ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘sys’, ‘ini’, ‘backports’,
 ‘ps’, ‘lazyeval’, ‘shiny’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘later’, ‘askpass’, ‘clipr’,
 ‘clisymbols’, ‘curl’, ‘fs’, ‘gh’, ‘purrr’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘whisker’, ‘yaml’,
 ‘processx’, ‘R6’, ‘assertthat’, ‘rex’, ‘htmltools’, ‘htmlwidgets’, 
 ‘magrittr’, ‘crosstalk’, ‘promises’, ‘mime’, ‘openssl’, ‘prettyunits’,
 ‘xopen’, ‘brew’, ‘commonmark’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘stringi’, ‘stringr’, ‘xml2’,
 ‘evaluate’, ‘praise’, ‘usethis’, ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘covr’, ‘crayon’, ‘desc’,
 ‘digest’, ‘DT’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘glue’, ‘git2r’, ‘httr’, ‘jsonlite’,
 ‘memoise’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘pkgload’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘remotes’, ‘rlang’,
 ‘roxygen2’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘rversions’, ‘sessioninfo’, ‘testthat’, ‘withr’
```

How does this make any sense? Is this expected, and if yes, how can I prevent it from happening? I am using R 3.5.3 with 0-Cloud mirror.

Comment: You've already asked the developer https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2133; no one else can really answer why they choose to depend on certain packages. This question doesn't seem to belong on Stack Overflow. This isn't the right place to discuss design decisions for individual packages.

Comment: @MrFlick what you fail to see is that I asked the developer only after I could not get an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

If you play around with `tools::package_dependencies()` a little bit you will eventually find that **devtools** imports the package **DT**, which in turn imports the package **crosstalk** which in turn imports the package **shiny**.

So why does **devtools** import **DT**?

A quick search of the github repo for **devtools** reveals the following `NEWS.md` item from version 2.2.0:

- Add the DT package as a dependency, so that `test_coverage()` and `test_coverage_file()` work without having to install additional packages (#2085).

Why did the package author make this choice? Well if you read the referenced [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2085) you'll see there was actually some disagreement about it between two devs and it seems like it was added because it was causing additional package installs that at least one of them found annoying.

This discussion was referenced in yet *another* issue with even more discussion [here](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2112) where other devs complained about it at length, including a comment recently by [yourself](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2112).

And thus, the snake that is this Q&A has now swallowed its tail.